# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject throw exception when retrieving JSON from Rest API

Tags: c#, json, node.js

I have an issue I cannot solve. I have a nodejs server that can send a simple json through a REST API.

```
var filename = 'latestVersion.json';
fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
     if (err) throw err;        
     filejson = JSON.parse(data.toString('utf8').replace(/^\uFEFF/, ''));
     res.json(data);
});
```

I then retrieve the json in my C# application:

```
class AppVersion
{
   public int major { get; set; }
   public int minor { get; set; }
   public int build { get; set; }
}

HttpWebRequest http = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)http.GetResponse();
string versionString = null;
using(System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
   versionString = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
if(versionString != null)
{
   AppVersion test = new AppVersion() { major = 1, minor = 1, build = 1 };
   string testStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test);
   var j = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppVersion>(versionString);
}
```

I then have an exception "Cannot cast or convert...." when deserializing. However, if I use the `testStr` everything goes well. Then I looked at the strings and found this :

```
testStr = "{\"major\":1,\"minor\":1,\"build\":1}"
versionString = "\"﻿{\\\"major\\\": 1, \\\"minor\\\": 1, \\\"build\\\": 1}\""
```

More strange, I tried to edit the `versionString` by hand removing the extra escape characters and I got still an error (the JSON visualizer says that it is badly formatted).

Any clue to solve this ?

Comment: What specific (raw) output do you see from node if you make the request in a browser?  Something is double escaping it somewhere along the line, but it's hard to tell if it's node, the C# code or maybe even just the debug visualiser.

Comment: You should know, that the exact exception is needed in those kind of errors.

Comment: I got this : `"{\"major\": 1, \"minor\": 1, \"build\": 1}"` when I browse

Comment: Right, that's not valid json - it's already escaped, so the issue is in the node code.

Comment: ok but if I remove the extra escaping characters, why does it not work either ? the debugger ?

Comment: Perhaps not removing them properly.  What are the contents of `latestVersion.json`, and are you aware that you're sending the actual contents rather than where you've done a replace on them?

Comment: Going out on a limb here - did you perhaps do the same thing as how you got hold of `testStr` for comparison purposes, then copied that directly into the file?

Comment: How stupid I am ! Thks @JamesThorpe, I was indeed not sending the right object...

Comment: So changing `res.json(data)` to `res.json(filejson)` was all that was needed?